# Liquibase 3.8 breaks columns defined with serial type in Postgres

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase-3.8.2 against Postgres 12. I used to have column definitions as:

```
<column name="ID" type="serial">
    <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" />
</column>
```

And it is respected in DB. After upgraded it from 3.6.2 to 3.8.2, the generated column is created as int4 instead of following serial definition. It is a breaking change difficult to understand the root cause of the issue. Is this change intentional? I cannot find any breaking change at https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html.

In mysql we can define the column as:

```
  <column name="id" autoIncrement="true" type="integer">
    <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" />
  </column>
```

But for PostgresSQL 12 it does not work. The only way to make it works, it is to stick on 3.6.3 and type as serial.

Comment: you can get the actual SQL calls for each generated column, can you see something changing there ? Also could not really found in the docu the actual mapping against Postgres Serial type, thus this might be your issue. Check this [mapping](https://dba-presents.com/index.php/liquibase/216-liquibase-3-6-x-data-types-mapping-table)

Comment: If you try to run the autoIncrement="true" version against postgresql, what datatype does it create it as?

Comment: Thanks @AntJavaDev, you are right. But until 3.6, serial can be used. serial is a datatype in postgres, check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: @NathanVoxland, int4. I think the related code is at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/IntType.java#L47. And the latest change introduced was: " postgresql >= 10: use identity columns for autoincrement ", https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/e768a263da512f1bca55addfe550e6279f6d0cf0